# Cannot comment on an answer, is it normal?

Tags: discusión, comentarios

I am unable to add a comment in [this answer](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/3941/1727), I've tried searching why on the help site but I couldn't find anything useful.

Is it normal for this to happen? How can I comment it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must have 50 reputation before you can leave a comment.  You can see a complete breakdown of when each privelege is earned in the [help section](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) of the site.

Comment: Well, what can I do if I find that that answer isn't ok and I wanted to state why it isn't?

Comment: You'll need to earn some more reputation before you can leave a comment.  You're more than half way there! :)

Comment: haha, ok, thanks.